# TypeError : submitHandler is not a function on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeerror

I am trying to create a todolist with react native but i got this error :
It happen when i press my button to add a new item list.

[image]

this is my code :

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button, FlatList, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';


import AddtodoInput from "../components/addToDoInput";


function Item({ title }) {
  return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}

export default App = () => {

  const [NewToDo, setToDo] = useState([
    {
      key: '1',
      text: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      text: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      text: 'Third Item',
    },
  ]);

  const pressHandler = (key)=>{
    setToDo((prevTodo)=>{
      return prevTodo.filter(todo => todo.key !== key);
    });
  }

  const submitHandler = (text) => {
    setToDo((prevTodo) => {
      return [
        {text: text, key:Math.random(). toString()},
          ...prevTodo
      ];
    })
  }

  return (
<View>
  <AddtodoInput submitHandler={submitHandler} />

  <FlatList
      data={NewToDo}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.text} />}
      pressHandler ={pressHandler}
      keyExtractor={item => item.key}
  />
</View>
  );
};
```

AddtoInput.js

```
import React, {useState}from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';


export default AddtodoInput = (submitHandler) => {

    const [text,setText] = useState('');


    const changeHandler = (val) => {
        setText(val);
    }

    return (
        <View>

            <TextInput style={styles.myCustomColor}
                       placeholder={'test'}
                       onChangeText ={changeHandler}

            />
            <Button onPress={() => submitHandler(text)} title={'add'}/>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    myCustomColor: {
        fontSize: 22,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the props in your **AddtoInput.js** incorrectly. The only that you need to change is the way that you are using the props in a functional component. Any functional component would have the parameter as a props object, so if you want to use any prop from this object then you need to use destructuring or you can use it directly with the object's dot notation.

For your case changing the below line in your **AddtoInput.js** would work:-

FROM =>

```
export default AddtodoInput = (submitHandler) => {
```

TO =>

```
export default AddtodoInput = ({submitHandler}) => {
```

Understand that this paramter in functional component has the object of all the props and you have to use any property from this object by either destructuring as above or you can use that property with dot notation as below:-

```
export default AddtodoInput = (props) => {

    const [text,setText] = useState('');


    const changeHandler = (val) => {
        setText(val);
    }

    return (
        <View>

            <TextInput style={styles.myCustomColor}
                       placeholder={'test'}
                       onChangeText ={changeHandler}

            />
            <Button onPress={() => props.submitHandler(text)} title={'add'}/>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the AddTodoInput component.

```
export default AddtodoInput = (submitHandler) => {
```

Props is an object and in your case submitHandler is just props renamed. Because your code is equal to:

```
export default AddtodoInput = (props) => {
```

Is just props with other name.

To solve this you can use

`export default AddtodoInput = ({ submitHandler }) => {`

or receive props and do `props.submitHandler` to get the function.